# JSON length Causing Facebook Post to Wall Functionality to Break in IE8 & IE9

Tags: facebook, json, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been using the Facebook Javascript SDK to post content from a CMS to a facebook fan page. It basically works by pulling the current pages content using jQuery and feeding it into FB.api function. Everything works fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc. The only problem is IE in which nothing happens, no error message, no javascript errors, nothing.

Here is the function I am using:

```
function Publish(){
    //variables pulled from page content like so:
    var fb_message = $('#content').text();

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',
    {
        access_token    : fb_token,
        name            : fb_name,
        message         : fb_message,
        link            : fb_link,
        picture         : fb_photo,
        caption         : fb_caption

    },function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert("Couldnt post"); 
        } else {
            alert('Posted');  
        }
    })
}
```

If I remove the `message` from the `FB.api` json, or limit the length of the string being sent to 850 chars it works fine even in IE, but I have no idea why? The string is just Loreum Ipsum, no odd characters or line breaks.

**Update** 
Actually seems that if I remove `caption, name, link, etc` and only post a 'message' in the json I can push a slightly longer `message` string through to facebook, which seems to point to the length of the json being some kind of problem...

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

**Update** 
I tried rewriting my functionality from scratch in a separate html file, still getting a problem in IE, so I have submitted a bug to Facebook. See what they have to say about it.

Comment: Thought I should add, tried debugging the JS, but it isn't returning any errors on the page...

Comment: The code you shown isn't even syntactically correct - there is an issue with quotes

Comment: Which quotes? if it was the `alert('Couldn't post')` ? That was my bad, I didn't copy in the exact code I'm using and had changed the error message. 

Otherwise it would be nice if you elaborated a bit more, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been recognized as a bug by the Facebook team, and they have plans to push a fix soon. You can see my bug report [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/369544316432727?browse=search_4fe0054b438304a16099011).

**UPDATE**
The fix was pushed, and the problem solved in IE9+. However IE7 and 8 still have problems with long strings. In fact they appear to have become more of a problem since the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The `message` parameter is deprecated,
you have to use the `description` parameter to post in a user feed,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: The Facebook developers reference for `post` doesn't say anything about the message field being depreciated? 

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

. Isn't `description` used for providing a small greyed out string of text displayed under a link? Thats the way it appears when I try it. I am trying to post a message to someones wall.

Comment: Yes, description used for providing a greyed out string, they pass the message to the description param. I can't find where/what the description character limit is, but check if the function is working with small strings (255max), if it works, you must write a function to count/remove the strings from your json response.

Comment: Hey Philip, thanks for the reply, but I should point out that I am not trying to post a description. As I mentioned earlier I am attempting to post text to a wall along with a link. It is the body (large black text) of the message that when too long is breaking the functionality in IE. 

[Here](http://i45.tinypic.com/6fmk20.jpg) is an example of the result I get from Chrome/Firefox/Safari. It is the black(body) text that when too long breaks the functionality in IE.